# Residual sum of squares in multiple outputs problem

Tags: multiple-regression

On ESL page 56, "...suppose $\mathrm{Cov}(\epsilon)=\Sigma$, then the multivariate weighted criterion $\mathrm{RSS}(B;\Sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i-f(x_i))^T\Sigma^{-1}(y_i-f(x_i))=\mathrm{tr}((Y-XB)\Sigma^{-1}(Y-XB)^T)$ arises naturally from multivariate Gaussian theory. Here $f(x)$ is the vector
function $(f_1(x),...,f_K(x))$, and $y_i$ the vector of K responses for observation i..."

My questions are:1. What is the definition of RSS in multiple outputs problem? 2.How to derive this equation?

I tried to think retroductively, even I know that $\Sigma^{-1}$ is a precision matrix, it didn't help to expand this equation and get the definition of RSS in this case.

Comment: Only intuition that I came away with is minimizing joint density of k Gaussian errors i.e. reducing the mahalanobis distance of the errors from zero

Answer (score 0):

You have answered #1 already; the formula you gave is RSS for multiple outputs in the general case where $\Sigma$ is specified as the covariance matrix for error vectors $\varepsilon_1, ..., \varepsilon_K$. Observation $i$ has outputs $Y_1, ..., Y_K$, and $y_i$ is the vector of those $K$ responses associated to observation $i$. Equation (3.40) is the form for correlated errors -- see (3.37) for the fully written-out version in the case of independent errors. If you expand out (3.40) by writing the vector-matrix multiplication, you will get a similar equation to (3.37) with the terms of $\Sigma^{-1}$ throughout.

For question 2: (3.37) is the sum of the $K$ individual single-output RSS equations. Recall the single-output RSS is $||Y-X\hat{\beta}||^2$, or equivalently $(Y-X\hat{\beta})^T(Y-X\hat{\beta})$, a real number -- or equivalently, the trace of a $1\times 1$ matrix. A generalization of this norm is to think of the trace of $A^T A$ for $A$ that isn't a vector. This is called the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product), and it's what's described in (3.38). All that remains is to show where that $\Sigma^{-1}$ comes from. We're modeling $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\Sigma)$. Therefore $\Sigma^{-1/2}\varepsilon \sim N(0,I)$ so the modified problem is solved by left-multiplying the equation by that same matrix and reducing it to the uncorrelated problem. Then $(\Sigma^{-1/2}Y-\Sigma^{-1/2}X\hat{\beta})^T(\Sigma^{-1/2}Y-\Sigma^{-1/2}X\hat{\beta}) = (Y-X\hat{\beta})^T\Sigma^{-1}(Y-X\hat{\beta})$, which then goes into the trace as in (3.38) and can be written like (3.40).